# How to send a file from html page using ajax to php which in turn stores in mysql database in column of type BLOB?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I have an HTML5 page that allows user to update his website, email and profile pic. Updating Website/email is not a problem for me that works.

However i want to know how can i send an image from the html input element to php file using ajax which in-turn stores that in MySql table which has a column of the type BLOB.

I have pasted my code below please advise is this correct?

1)HTML File

```
    <label for="website">Website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" id="website" data-clear-btn="true">


    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-clear-btn="true">



    <label for="uploadimg" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Upload Image of Advertisement:</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadimg" id="uploadimg" placeholder="Upload Image of Advertisement..">


    <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" onclick="updateUserProfile()">
```

2)Javascript File

```
function updateUserProfile(){

var website=document.getElementById("website").value;
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var image=document.getElementById("uploadimg").value;

$.post("php/updateUserProfile.php",
  {
    website:website,
    email:email,
    image:image
  });

}
```

3) PHP File

```
$website = $_POST['website'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$image= $_POST['image'];

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE profileinformation SET Website='".trim($website)."', Image ='".($image)."'  Where email='".$email."' ");
```

Comment: Have a look at : http://au1.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php this will give you all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery Form plugin for this kind of thing and did wonders for me. You can upload real time an image.

*Download link for jquery form:* http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download

*Ref link for this tutorial:* http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php

Here is a simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="processupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
  <input name="ImageFile" id="imageInput" type="file" />
  <input type="submit"  id="submit-btn" value="Upload" />
  <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading-img" style="display:none;" alt="Please Wait"/>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
            target:   '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
            resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 

     $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);  //Ajax Submit form            
            // return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
            return false; 
        }); 
});</script>
```

**The Before submit function:**

```
//function to check file size before uploading.
function beforeSubmit(){
    //check whether browser fully supports all File API
   if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
    {

        if( !$('#imageInput').val()) //check empty input filed
        {
            $("#output").html("Are you kidding me?");
            return false
        }

        var fsize = $('#imageInput')[0].files[0].size; //get file size
        var ftype = $('#imageInput')[0].files[0].type; // get file type


        //allow only valid image file types 
        switch(ftype)
        {
            case 'image/png': case 'image/gif': case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
                break;
            default:
                $("#output").html("<b>"+ftype+"</b> Unsupported file type!");
                return false
        }

        //Allowed file size is less than 1 MB (1048576)
        if(fsize>1048576) 
        {
            $("#output").html("<b>"+fsize +"</b> Too big Image file! <br />Please reduce the size of your photo using an image editor.");
            return false
        }

        $('#submit-btn').hide(); //hide submit button
        $('#loading-img').show(); //hide submit button
        $("#output").html("");  
    }
    else
    {
        //Output error to older unsupported browsers that doesn't support HTML5 File API
        $("#output").html("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    ############ Edit settings ##############
    $ThumbSquareSize        = 200; //Thumbnail will be 200x200
    $BigImageMaxSize        = 500; //Image Maximum height or width
    $ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
    $DestinationDirectory   = '/home/website/ajax-image-upload/uploads/'; //specify upload directory ends with / (slash)
    $Quality                = 90; //jpeg quality
    ##########################################

    //check if this is an ajax request
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
        die();
    }

    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
            die('Something wrong with uploaded file, something missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
    }

    // Random number will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 

    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])); //get image name
    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // get original image size
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Temp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //get file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

    //Let's check allowed $ImageType, we use PHP SWITCH statement here
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            //Create a new image from file 
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
    }

    //PHP getimagesize() function returns height/width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
    //Get first two values from image, width and height. 
    //list assign svalues to $CurWidth,$CurHeight
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);

    //Get file extension from Image name, this will be added after random name
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

    //remove extension from filename
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName); 

    //Construct a new name with random number and extension.
    $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;

    //set the Destination Image
    $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumbnail name with destination directory
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; // Image with destination directory

    //Resize image to Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
    if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {
        //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
        if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
            {
                echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
            }
        /*
        We have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
        We can now output image to user's browser or store information in the database
        */
        echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="uploads/'.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName.'" alt="Thumbnail"></td>';
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="uploads/'.$NewImageName.'" alt="Resized Image"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

        /*
        // Insert info into database table!
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO myImageTable (ImageName, ThumbName, ImgPath)
        VALUES ($DestRandImageName, $thumb_DestRandImageName, 'uploads/')");
        */

    }else{
        die('Resize Error'); //output error
    }
}


// This function will proportionally resize image 
function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight); 
    $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
    $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);
    $NewCanves          = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);

    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees memory   
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
    return true;
    }

}

//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original size!
function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{    
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //abeautifulsite.net has excellent article about "Cropping an Image to Make Square bit.ly/1gTwXW9
    if($CurWidth>$CurHeight)
    {
        $y_offset = 0;
        $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
        $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
    }else{
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
        $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
    }

    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize); 
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize, $iSize, $square_size, $square_size))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees memory   
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
    return true;

    }

}
```